# AUCTeX: turn off autoindent

Tags: editors, auctex

This isn't TeX, per se, but it is about writing TeX, so perhaps it is appropriate.  I find that AUCTeX's autoindent works in a way that runs counter to how I work.  In case I am not clear, for instance, I like to have footnotes indented as below.  When I type the close curly braces and ENTER AUCTeX will bring the footnote back to the first column.  I move it back and start a new line, as below, and when I type "paragraph." and hit ENTER it moves "Start" by two spaces.

```
end.\footnote{%
    This is a footnote.}

Start of a new paragraph.
Second line
```

Whe it happens once it is an annoyance.  Hundreds of times is an issue.

I've spent too much time tweaking autoindent and at this point I'd rather just indent by hand.  I've searched for how to turn it off in a number of places, including here and on emacs sites, without enlightenment.  At the moment this is my .emacs file, but I'm just flailing.

```
;; JH trying to turn off AUCTeX indenting
(setq LaTeX-indent-environment-list '())
(setq LaTeX-indent-level 0)
(setq LaTeX-item-indent 0)
(setq LaTeX-left-right-indent-level 0)
(setq TeX-brace-indent-level 0)
```

Comment: do you want to turn off auto-fill-mode entirely (`M-x auto-fill-mode` ) ?

Comment: Don't have any emacs to test anymore, so this is just a not so strong hypothesis, but are you sure some `0` shouldn't be replaced with `nil` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I did not mean to ask about autofill, I meant autoindent, where when you hit <enter> AUCTeX will change the indent of the line.  I edited the post to try to be clearer.

Comment: @sztruks I am clearly doing something wrong, but I think that those are numbers to indent by.

Comment: @JimHefferon hmm doesn't for me, but then I last configured auctex last century:-) `C-h k` suggest <enter> runs the function set by the customisable variable TeX-newline-function so perhaps you want to customise that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[David Carlile has a point](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/468047/auctex-turn-off-autoindent/468093#comment1177583_468047) in mentioning `TeX-newline-function`, which is, by default, set to `newline`. Looking the latter's docstring, we find:

> If ‘electric-indent-mode’ is enabled, this indents the final new line
>   that it adds, and reindents the preceding line.  To just insert
>   a newline, use M-x electric-indent-just-newline.

I can reproduce the behavior you describe with my settings, and it appears `electric-indent-mode` is on by default (I don't have it explicitly in my init file, and it was on here). Indeed, disabling it, the editor does let me "Start of a new paragraph." without the extra spaces.

So, disabling `electric-indent-mode` (in LaTeX-mode, or everywhere, as you prefer) or setting `TeX-newline-function` to `electric-indent-just-newline` may be two good alternatives for you.

One sensible way to disable `electric-indent-mode` for specific modes is suggested at [Disabling electric-indent-mode for one mode (latex mode) only](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/30148/18951). Which is to create a function to disable `electric-indent-local-mode` and then hook it to the mode(s) of interest:

```
(defun JH/remove-electric-indent-mode ()
  (electric-indent-local-mode -1))

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'JH/remove-electric-indent-mode)
(add-hook 'tex-mode-hook 'JH/remove-electric-indent-mode)
;; and so on
```

However, you seem to be fighting auto-indent in general, when it should be there to help you. For example, the reason in the first place why "When I type the close curly braces and ENTER AUCTeX will bring the footnote back to the first column." seems to be that you set `(setq TeX-brace-indent-level 0)`. Furthermore, the fact that "when I type "paragraph." and hit ENTER it moves "Start" by two spaces" seems to indicate you have indentation set to two spaces. However, when you manually indented your footnote, you added **four** spaces.

The default behavior seems to rely heavily on auto-indent doing the right thing, which makes sense. However, I think you could get things to work quite close to what your are picturing, along with auto-indent, with:

```
(setq TeX-brace-indent-level 4)
```

Which will set your footnotes (and any other open braces) indented to four spaces, while the rest remains with two spaces. That alone should allow you to type what you describe.

Comment: `electric-indent-mode` changed behaviour at Emacs 24.4, see [here](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2014-11/msg00619.html) and it is nightmarish with AUCTeX mode. I turn it off for tex in my init file. Also for some other modes.

Comment: @jfbu Thank you for the pointer, I wasn't aware of this discussion. Though it doesn't really interfere much with my own use, I do agree messing with <Ret> default behavior in this way is quite intrusive. Given your experience with the matter, would you say I should revise the advice in the answer? How do you usually disable `electric-indent-mode` for AUCTeX?

Comment: For reference, one sensible way to disable `electric-indent-mode` for `LaTeX-mode`: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/30148/18951

Comment: I had forgotten but I turned it off as part of a hook to `lisp-mode`, see [gist](https://gist.github.com/jfbu/422ed9322492ced7a932079fc462e302) and it is inherited by tex mode in particular. And my `initial-major-mode` is left unmodified (`lisp-interaction-mode`) (I don't know if that last remark has any relevance, it seems to regard  `*scratch*` buffer)

Comment: @jfbu Thank you for digging it up. My hunch there is that, when you open Emacs, your major mode is `lisp-mode`, as you add `(electric-indent-mode 0)` to the lisp-mode hook, that will disable `electric-indent-mode` globally every time you start up, because it is a global mode (as far as I understood). That's my guess of why this works for you.

Comment: @gusbro Thank you.  If you add the link tot he emacs stack exchange then I'll be pleased to accept the answer.  (BTW, I only included the footnote behavior as an example of a larger effect.  The .emacs I gave is where I was when I finally threw up my hands and decided to pester people such as yourself with the question.)

Comment: @JimHefferon I was actually unaware of `electric-indent-mode` workings, because it felt sensible to me. But it was nice to get a better grasp on it. And, I must admit, depending on what you expect, it does make sense to disable it selectively or altogether.

Comment: @gusbrs yes your analysis is convincing... (at some point I had `initial-major-mode` modifed to text mode, and I have very vague memories of some interference with how I turned `electric-indent-mode` off, but anyway, that does not matter here). I have also a hook for rst-mode, I post an excerpt [here](https://gist.github.com/jfbu/90f1efd401481a35adab0a5528ae5bbb)

Comment: @jfbu I won't tell you to change anything 'cause, as we all know: "If it ain't broke, don't fix it!". Besides, I definitely like your `; Arrrggh!` comments.  ;-)

Comment: You don’t need to define an auxiliary function to disable `electric-indent-local-mode`: it is enough to use `(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda () (electric-indent-local-mode -1)))`.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek3.0 True, you don't have to, if you don't want to. But there are some advantages to it, see, for example, a recent discussion on Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/fce9wz/lambda_vs_defun/